# How to add a string and int and sort by the int

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to program a simple console program that accepts a string and integer as input, enters them into an array, sorts them by the integer, and returns the contents accordingly. I've been battling this program for a long time, so thanks a lot for the help :).

Comment: Maybe show us your code?

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

On approach would be to create a class that holds both the string and int parts of the info.  You can create an instance for each int/string pair.  Then you can put those instances in an array.

You can then sort the array using [Arrays.sort](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29).  Note that your class will have to implement `Comparable` as the linked API documentation says.

Comment: Thanks, was just about to show my code but I guess this helped me all the way :)

Comment: I would advice you to learn how to make a sorting algorithm first than use Arrays.sort. I am all for high level programing but you must have a feeling for the basics.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of array, use `TreeMap<Integer, String>`. TreeMap is sorted by the 'key' in the natural order. All you have to do is iterate over it.

Solution given by amit is also ok.

Answer (score 0):

you should write a class with int and String as fields, and implement a [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for this class. insert your elements to the array, and just use [Arrays.sort()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to sort it.

Answer (score 0):

I am going against the current here. All have advice you to use Arrays.sort() I advice you not to.

And here is the reason. When starting to learn programming I find it a funny and very good learning form to implement algorithms your self and you will have a far grater understanding of Computer Sciences if you have implemented sorting a few times your self. So do your own sorting algorithm and when you fell comfty with that then use Arrays.sort().

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use an array for input unless you know the number of entries. You can Use ArrayList so you don't need to know.

```
class StringInt implement Comparable<StringInt> {
    final String string;
    final int num;

    public StringInt(String string, int num) { 
       this.string = string; 
       this.num = num; 
    }

    public int compareTo(StringInt si) {
        return num > si.num ? +1 : num < si.num ? -1 : 0;
    }
}

List<StringInt> list = new ArraysList<StringInt>();

// add element.
list.add(new StringInt("Hello", 1));

// sort them
Collections.sort(list);
```